# How Do I escape a + in a PHP Regex?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to escape a + sign in a PHP regex for a project, and whatever I've tried does not seem to work unfortunately.

This is my code:

```
 if(!preg_match('/(6-12|7-12|10\+|8-14|9-14|10-16)\b/m', $ageRange)){
        $boolValidatieOk = 0;
        $strValidationMessage .= "\t<p>Age Range must be a value <em>USED</em> by Lego. EG.(\"6-12\" \"7-12\" \"14+\")</p>";
    }
```

and unfortunately I cannot escape a +.

I've tried \+, \\+ and \\\\+ But it doesn't work! could someone please help me!

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? What makes you think the plus sign needs to be escaped here? You trying to match someone who literally types in "10+" or you are trying to match 100?

Comment: Sorry ! Yes, I am trying to match a 10+ literally. It's for age ranges in lego sets, and If they don't enter a real age range for a lego set, it is supposed to trigger the validation! Sorry about the poor context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word boundary `\b` was causing issues, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/H2jMcW/1)

Comment: Thank you so much!